# compiler.plugin is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I run npm run start command and I am getting this error:-

Failed to compile.

compiler.plugin is not a function

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ipfs-image-app@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ipfs-image-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yash mudgal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-28T06_56_44_910Z-debug.log

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

for error --compiler.plugin is not a function

npm install --save-dev webpack-shell-plugin-next

for error --npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Cleaning Cache and Node_module are not enough. Follow this steps:

1-npm cache clean --force

2-delete node_modules folder

3-delete package-lock.json file

4 -npm install

run these commands before npm start.