# Compiler.plugin is not a function on npm statrt/npm run build after upgrading to webpack 5

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

When I run `npm start` after upgrading my react app to Webpack 5, it's throwing **compiler.plugin is not a function error**

I have tried this solution already [compiler.plugin is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71291543/compiler-plugin-is-not-a-function)

It didn't work.

I tried upgrading all the plugins and removing the deprecated plugins then I got **TypeError: webpack.NamedModulesPlugin is not a constructor**
So I commented **new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()** in my **webpack.config.js** and now I am getting

Failed to compile.

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

```
configuration has an unknown property 'applyWebpackOptionsDefaults'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, experiments?, extends?, externals?, externalsPresets?, externalsType?, ignoreWarnings?, infrastructureLogging?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?, optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, snapshot?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   -> Options object as provided by the user.
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack >= v2.0.0 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           applyWebpackOptionsDefaults: …
         }
       })
     ]
```